# How to solve Gurobi Error Divisor must be a constant

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

```py
from gurobipy import *
import pandas as p
import numpy as np
d={
   (1,1):2,(1,2):3,(1,3):3,(1,4):5,
   (2,1):2,(2,2):3,(2,3):3,(2,4):5,
   (3,1):2,(3,2):3,(3,3):3,(3,4):5,
   (4,1):2,(4,2):3,(4,3):3,(4,4):5,
   (5,1):2,(5,2):3,(5,3):3,(5,4):5,
}
P,p=multidict({1:1,2:1,3:2,4:2,5:2})
W,w=multidict({1:2,2:2,3:2,4:2})
D=100
total_p=sum([i for i in p.values()])
total_w=sum([j for j in w.values()])
if total_w/total_p<1:
    R= total_w/total_p
else :
    R=1
print(R)
model=Model("keibi optimizer")
x={}
for i in P:
    for j in W:
        x[i,j]=model.addVar(vtype="C",name="x(%s,%s)"%(i,j)) 
model.update()
for j in W:
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j] for i in P) == w[j],name='Demand(%s)' %j) 
for i in P:
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j] for j in W) <= p[i],name='Capacity(%s)' %i) 
for i in P:
    for j in W:
        model.addConstr(d[i,j]*x[i,j],"<=",D*x[i,j])  
model.setObjective(quicksum(D-(sum((d[i,j]*x[i,j]/x[i,j]) for j in W if x!=0))for i in P),GRB.MAXIMIZE)
model.optimize()
print("Optimal value:", model.ObjVal/(total_p*D))
for(i,j) in x:
        print("sending quantity %10s from factory %3s to customer %3s" %(x[i,j], j, i))
```

I made the above program using python gurobi9.12. But I cannot run the program.

error message

```
Divisor must be a constant
```

I guess `model.setObjective(quicksum(D-(sum((d[i,j]*x[i,j]/x[i,j]) for j in W if x!=0))for i in P),GRB.MAXIMIZE)` is complicated.

I want to make a program using the formula in the photo below as the objective function.

What should I do? Please help me.
[image]

Comment: I cannot fathom the reason for writing something like `d[i,j]*x[i,j]/x[i,j]`.

Comment: sorry. I was wrong.Σ_j∈W d[i,j]*x[i,j]/Σj∈W x[i,j]. This is Average distance travel.

Comment: Gurobi cannot handle divisions. But it can work with quadratic terms. As `z=x/y` can be written as `z*y=x`, we are in good shape.

Comment: Thank you.But Σj∈W x[i,j] is a two-dimensional array and a variable . Also, the calculation of the total sum is an obstacle. So I cannot solve it even if I change it to multiplication.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, the result of `y[i] = Σj∈W x[i,j]` is actually one dimensional. Just add extra variables and constraints, and only use multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

So let's focus on: `Σ_j∈W d[i,j]*x[i,j]/Σj∈W x[i,j]`. First, the math is confusing. I never, ever have a sum over j inside a sum over j. We don't know what j is inside the inner sum.

I'll use the notation:

```
 sum(j, d[i,j]*x[i,j]/y[i])
 y[i] = sum(j, x[i,j])
```

for our problem. Now we can do:

```
 sum(j, d[i,j]*z[i,j])
 y[i]*z[i,j] = x[i,j]   for all i,j
 y[i] = sum(j, x[i,j])  for all i
 y[i],z[i,j] free variables
```

As you can see, there is no division anymore. Note that we introduced a non-convex quadratic constraint here. That is a bit expensive but better than division which cannot be handled by Gurobi at all. Further note that we allow `y[i]=0` here (multiplication by zero is allowed, but dividing by zero is not).

In general, if you see `z=x/y`, you need to consider using `x=z*y`.

Comment: Thank you. I try to make the problem